# The importance of having a Rebbe for non-halachic subjects

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

It's easily understandable why a person [must have a Rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi) to ask questions to in matters of halacha (a posek). If I remember correctly, many mefarshim explain one of the 2 statements of "asei le'cha rav" in Pirkei Avos to mean just that.

My question is: Is there also an idea of having a single Rabbi as your 'go to' person for matters of hashkafah and middos related issues and idea's? Can a person ask around about non-halachic matters and choose what to go by on a case by case basis (which is not allowed when it comes to psak halacha)?

Comment: אבות דרבי נתן seems to explain one of them to include Medrash and Aggada - which would seem to be about Hashkafa.

Comment: The specific issur brought in Shulchan Aruch about not asking around does not apply to Hashkafa. That being said, there are many benefits to having a master (Rav) in these areas, too. Chassidim are very into this (the primary purpose of a Rebbi is not halachik), but the classical sources all support the idea to greater or lesser degrees.